# Drag functionality only working from right to left, but not from left to right

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, drag

Below is the code(not very elegant or complete, but working) for the dragging functionality in react version 17. Dragging the element works from left to right, but not from right to left. Can anyone please advise the issue or is something is missing.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    const Draggables = (props) => {
      const [dragging, setDragging] = useState(false);
      const [pos, setPos] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (dragging) {
          document.addEventListener("mousemove", { onMouseMove });
          document.addEventListener("mouseup", { onMouseUp });
        } else if (!dragging) {
          document.removeEventListener("mousemove", { onMouseMove });
          document.removeEventListener("mouseup", { onMouseUp });
        }
      }, [dragging]);
    
      const mouseDown = (e) => {
        // only left mouse button
        if (e.button !== 0) return;
         setDragging(true);
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
      };
    
      const onMouseUp = (e) => {
        setDragging(false);
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
      };
    
      const onMouseMove = (e) => {
        if (!dragging) return;
        setPos({
          x: e.pageX,
        });
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="draggable"
          onMouseDown={mouseDown}
          onMouseMove={onMouseMove}
          onMouseUp={onMouseUp}
    
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            left: `${pos.x}px`,
            top: 50 + "px",
          }}
        >
          D
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Draggables;
```

Below is the corresponding CSS.

```
    .draggable {
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 4px;
      height: 4px;
      border-radius: 50px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any library??

Comment: @Soheb just react 17, not using any library and thats is the goal to create this component without using any third party library

Comment: Try adding x : 0 - pos.left while setting state

Comment: Did you try above mentioned code??

Comment: I did, but didn't work, but thats a good point to begin with.

Comment: Create a fiddle or sandbox.., will continue in chat later

Comment: How can we chat?

Comment: Will message in sometime have created the codesandbox??

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/12218522/soheb, I couldn't find a room here. Please check my profile here for my contact and please send me a note. We can begin from there. or please share yours. Thanks!